# Issue starting out with java

Tags: java, javac

I got a problem starting out with java.

I set my path as

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin

and made the basic `Hello.java` notepad file. The problem is when I try to compile using:

```
C:\>javac
```

I get an error:

> C:\ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What did I do wrong/What may be the cause of this?

Comment: you just need to write `javac filename.java`

Comment: first of all check if you have java installed or not by typing java -version.

Comment: As Gaur93 said, check if your java is on the classpatk with 'java -version'. You can check your environment varriables using echo %PATH%.

Comment: Don't literally type "C:>javac". Just type "javac". The "C:\>" is the prompt in the command window.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Thank you for your replies i will try everything right now

Comment: Everything you suggested worked the problem was that i was using c:\ in the command prompt thanks for helping out this noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first try to set java home from your command prompt like this -

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin
```

Then from terminal try to check whether it is installed properly, using -

```
java -version
```

If everything is correct then you would see message like this -

```
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Then you should set JAVA_HOME and PATH at your computer using this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)

Answer (score 2):

The reason CMD gives that error is because you wrote `C:>` in the command, and that is unnecessary.

You simply need to write

```
javac Hello.java
```

And that compiles the file.
When your CMD directory is that of the file.
After compiling, run

```
java Hello
```

To run it

Answer (score 0):

To start with, please, check, that java has been installed properly by typing in cmd:

```
java -version
```

Then, to compile some source file you need to provide this file as a parameter to java compiler. Like this:

```
javac Hello.java
```

After that, you should get your code compiled and `Hello.class` file should appear.